# GWT & Visualisations API - ImageLineGraph display options

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I'm displaying a ImageLineChart via my little GWT application and I just wanted to add some display options, namely:

chm=s,000000,0,1,7.5

Which is just a little black square node on series 1 (0) point number 2(1).  I tried appending the above string onto one of my current ImageLineChart url's and hey presto, there appeared the black node.

In the GWT application I used:

`options.set("chm", "s,000000,0,1,7.5");`

As I couldn't find an actual method for setting "chm", so I tried a general-purpose set() method, as above.

This doesn't seem to be working and checking the URL in debug I can't find any mention of this chm parameter which I thought I'd have set.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance
Tony

Comment: Maybe you are running into this issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=434